# What is in the package delivered to Hank Pym?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*, Captain America gets Hank Pym out of his lab by pretending to be a delivery man. He mentions that the package is glowing, prompting Hank to ask if anybody had opened it, and then to rush off when he finds out that someone supposedly had opened it.

Was there any specific reference, or is it just a throwaway line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, it's possible Pym was *not* expecting anything and was taken by surprise upon hearing he has to deal with deliver stuff. However, assuming he did, I'd infer the same thing than I did on [the same question on SFF](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/211061/98028):

Radioactive stuff, most probably, as it was (supposedly, but Pym didn't seem to refute the possibility) glowing and gave the workers handling it some kind of illness.

It can be noticed that back in [*Tales to Astonish* #35 (1962)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Tales_to_Astonish_Vol_1_35), one of the first Ant-Man comics, Pym was tasked to make a gas to render people immune to radioactivity, which probably implies studying of radioactive material first. Possibly *Endgame* was making a reference to that.

[image: Pym is tasked to develop a radioactivity​ immunity]

Pym has been established in the MCU to be a bit of a "mad genius" at times, tampering with iffy physics (failed Pym particles reduce their targets to goo, remember a certain sheep?). Thus, a (more boring) out-of-universe explanation is most likely to have a funny scene, where Pym and the viewers gradually realise what the package is, as the "clueless" person at the other end of the line still doesn't understand.

Comment: Might I suggest a minor edit? That question was asking what he was *expecting* to be in it, while this one seems to be asking what was actually in it. This answer appears to be affirming that there was an actual package with contents (which seems highly unlikely). As a result, I found myself oddly tempted to upvote the other answer, but not this (identical) one.

Comment: @T.E.D. will edit to clarify, but as Pym didn't react with a "WTF, I never ordered anything, especially radioactive stuff", I do think he was expecting something, yes. At least, I don't remember him seeming particularly baffled a package was waiting for him

Comment: My impression was that mundane tasks like ordering supplies wouldn't be something he'd typically personally involve himself in (his initial reaction on the phone kind of bears that out). Add to that the fact that he's likely in a position where the government might ship him any odd "glowy" thing it happens across to look at and/or identify, and that he's likely to be shipping glowing things out to other agencies and receiving them back all the time, and it may well be a low-level expectation that such items might be arriving at his lab every now and then.